# In Cypress, set a token in localStorage before test

Tags: browser, e2e-testing, cypress

I want to login and set a `localStorage` token on the client (specifically [`jwt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token))

How can I accomplish this using `cy.request`, as suggested in the Cypress Documentation?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Here's an example of adding a command `cy.login()` that you can use in any Cypress test, or put in a `beforeEach` hook.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => { 
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/login',
    body: {
      user: {
        email: 'jake@jake.jake',
        password: 'jakejake',
      }
    }
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', resp.body.user.token)
  })

})
```

Then in your test:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.login()
})
```

Comment: This works, but the value gets overwritten when I visit the app URL. My app seems can't read the created local storage.

Comment: You need to navigate to your page before setting localStorage

Comment: I would also recommend to use cy.window() (see Cypress docs) to get the window object of the active page :

`cy.window().then(win => win.localStorage.setItem('jwt', resp.body.user.token))`

Comment: cy.window().then(win => win.localStorage.setItem('jwt', resp.body.user.token))
Works fine, thanks @guillaumepn

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: Doesn't this make a log in request to the server *on every test*? I assume what most users want is to log in once, or once per test file.

Comment: @guillaumepn That doesn't help much when you're calling functions that use window somewhere down the callchain. It would be pretty awkward to write your library functions solely with cypress in mind so you can drill a window object down wherever you need it...

Answer (score 29):

As an extra, you can also use the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) package to persist localStorage between tests, so login request will be made only once:

In support/commands.js:

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => { 
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/login',
    body: {
      user: {
        email: 'jake@jake.jake',
        password: 'jakejake',
      }
    }
  })
  .its('body')
  .then(body => {
    cy.setLocalStorage("jwt", body.user.token);
  })
});
```

Then, in your tests:

```js
before(() => {
  cy.login();
  cy.saveLocalStorage();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.restoreLocalStorage();
});
```

Comment: Only worked for me with the package you indicated. Thanks

Comment: According to the docs on npm you should clear the storage in the `before()`, then in `beforeEach` do the restore and visit, then `afterEach` save the localstorage. `Note the usage of beforeEach and afterEach for preserving localStorage between all tests. Also clearLocalStorageSnapshot is used in the before statement to avoid possible conflicts with other test files preserving localStorage.`

Comment: from where we get this please?
cy.setLocalStorage("jwt", body.user.token);
i am trying to set it but it is failing at the body.user.token part

Comment: Hi @ZombiePie, the code shown in the example is intended to be useful only to describe how to use the `cy.setLocalStorage` command. It would work really only if you have an API started in `http://localhost:3000/api/users/login` returning a response with a body in JSON with the property `user.token`. You have to adapt the login request and response to your own case.

Comment: I am trying to use: https://blog.digital-craftsman.de/keep-local-storage-in-cypress/
i have a question, will the system still login everytime when i apply this?

Comment: I don't understand you very well @ZombiePie. This answer is related to the usage of the `cypress-localstorage-commands` Cypress plugin, and you are mentioning a blog post entry without relation to it.

Answer (score 20):

I've used something along the lines of bkuceras answer for a while now. Recently I've run into an issue when testing multiple roles/logins throughout tests. Basically what is happening is I log in as an admin and do one test, then I log in as a non admin and do a second test. The first test runs fine and ends (cypress clears local storage) however there are still some xhr requests running from the first test when the second test starts. These xhr requests no longer see the token which triggers my app to see a 401 unauthorized error and clear local storage (including my non admin token I have set). Now the 2nd test fails because that non admin token is not available in local storage.

Ultimately my solution was to prefetch the token before the test then set the token in the onBeforeLoad function of visit. This ensures the token is not cleared by any race condition before your visit command.

```
cy.visit('/app', {
    onBeforeLoad: function (window) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', myToken);
    }
})
```

Really this is a pretty unique edge case, but heres hoping it may help someone as I've spent many hours finding this solution.

Comment: Probably a cleaner solution than most. You can even make it into a custom command that always sets the item.

Comment: Although not specific to the question asked, this helped me as I am using cy.visit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are open for the experimental mode, I highly recommend to use the cy.session to store the token:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  cy.session([username, password], () => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/login',
      body: { username, password },
    }).then(({ body }) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', body.token)
    })
  })
})
```

For more information, please check the official cypress documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session

Answer (score 0):

I think that title should be updated for this topic. JWT token is main potin for this discussion!

The main question was about JWT token but in general, all modern applications are using OIDC [Microsoft article - v2-protocols-oidc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) / [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token) and here is a very tricky situation to get an access using just generating tokens by API call.
I found [here](https://sandrino.dev/blog/writing-cypress-e2e-tests-with-auth0) that
[image]
and will check it with my app. But be sure that you are cool in JS and have good assistance from your DevTeam ;)

Answer (score -6):

I have spent so many hours on this and finally I can safely conclude that it will never work for OAuth requests.

It may work for local server but not when you getting token for authentication.

Comment: You can make a request to retrieve the data you require on OAuth provider.