# How can I remove an overlay

Tags: html, css, popup, cypress, overlay

I receive a series of product names from an API, which I input into the "Main Search Bar" repeatedly.

[image: Main Search Bar]

While emulating the behavior of a first-time visitor to the page, I encounter a pop-up overlay which renders all elements unresponsive, with the exception of itself.

[image: Elements]

[image: The pop-up]

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
                      if ($body.find('.overlay').is(":visible")) {
                          cy.get('.overlay').click()
                      }
                  })
```

Comment: This is the best way, but is `.overlay` always present? Or is it sometimes not in the DOM?

Comment: Always present for first user.

Answer (score 0):

[You can also modify the element to not appear,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47142265/11625850) assuming that the `data-dr-hide` attribute is what determines if the overlay appears.

```js
cy.get('.popup').invoke('attr', 'data-dr-hide', 'true')
  .should('have.attr', 'data-dr-hide', 'true');
// the `true` may or may not need to be in quotes
```

If you can identify the [cookie](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie) or [local storage or session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50820733/11625850) value that determines if you are a first-time visitor, it can also be beneficial to just load the page with that value set to whatever says you are not a first-time visitor.

```js
// pseudo-code
describe('My Tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/url')
      .then(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('firstTimeVisitor', false);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('firstTimeVisitor', false);
    }).setCookie('firstTimeVisitor', false);
  });

  it('validates X', () => {
    // code here
  });
});
```